# Workarounds for detecting key presses outside a Javascript application in-browser

Tags: javascript, browser

I am currently working on an HTML/Javascript doc that would run on a second monitor in browser while the user is outside the page in a different application. While the user would be able to tab into the page and make their inputs then, I would like there to be a functionality for them to do so while tabbed out of the page for accessibility, ideally via keyboard keys. However, I am aware that JS does not support event listeners like this while you are outside the page due to security concerns.

Essentially, I am asking whether there exists an easy workaround for this such as running a tertiary application which has the ability to listen to key press events tabbed out, and interfaces with the HTML/JS doc in browser (via inputs or command execution), and if so how would I set up such a system. I am relatively new to JS and even less experienced in other languages (bar MATLAB), so if a better method exists than this then that might be plan B

As said before, I know that JS by itself cannot handle key press event listeners outside the application, however I don't know if a workaround is possible by using another application in the background. I also don't know whether such an application is easily available, or whether I would need to programme it myself (and if so what language to use and how to do it). I've tried looking into something like this, but I couldn't find anything.

Comment: Yeah, you're going to have to write a native application for each platform you plan to deploy on, and then shuffle that data back to your web application.  I am curious though if you can elaborate on your specific use case.  There may be better methods than keyboard key capture.  For example, do you control this other application?  Can it send data to your web application?  Also, if this is related to media hotkeys, the MediaSession API can be used for this.

Comment: The application I'm tabbed into is a multi-player game so I can't really modify its files, the browser application/doc is used to keep track of stuff in-game. The game can't send data to my web application as it's not designed for this unfortunately.
I will look into MediaSession API and see if it is applicable.

Comment: Try [autohotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com), it's kinda designed for things like this (and much more)

Comment: Thank you, I will try this. Hopefully it will work with Edge. I will update once I have tested it